# OSM and imported points do not match in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, import, point-creation

I am trying to insert new coordinate system to the QGIS ( ferom excel comma delimited file), but unfortunately the coordinates do not overlap the correct point in OSM inside.

Below there are screenshots of the data and the result in QGIS, by how much the points are off the Los Angeles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use 
Crtl + H in excel to change . to ,
and define the good SCR

Comment: can you please show the working window of the `Add Delimited Text Layer` ? Most likely @LM10 is right, and while importing the CSV, QGIS interprets lat&long as 34&-188 without decimals, that is why they all are placed at one location.

Comment: How do you transform your lat-longs to CRS 26745? What is the datum of your input? Are the points exactly at the same location (i.e a loss of decimals) or are they still at distinct (but wrong) locations?

Comment: The dot should be fine. As we can see from the excel screenshot it is recognized as the decimal separator in the user locale. The value is recognized as a number with 4 decimal digits, so the dot is fine.

Comment: NO, Taras. The points arent at same places. Upon zooming the points are scattered but as they are closely scattered, it seems like a point whule i zoom out. I just wanted to show how far the points are out of range from where they should be. Changing '.' to ',' didn't help. What CRS should i use, so that the points falls on exact position??

Comment: Those Lats and Longs show up northwest of Los Angeles. I can't think of any way to make them show up in the Pacific Ocean.

Comment: @Pointdump what CRS did you use, or did you just looked up the coordinates in google?

Comment: I used both EPSG:4326 and EPSG:4267 in QGIS with your list of points.

Answer (score 2):

you have imported lat-longs, maybe in CRS 4326, as if it was coordinates in
[26745](https://epsg.io/26745) (NAD27 / California zone V).

The values are outside the projection bounds, so their location is now highly distorted and falls in the ocean.

To fix it, import the csv using the proper CRS (4326 or else), then reproject your data to 26745.

Ex below: coordinate `-118;34` imported as `26745`:
[image]